# If statement within echo?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, echo

I was wondering if it's possible to have an if statement within an echo.

I have if statement which works fine when echoing results through the a while loop...  This is the statement:

```
<div><?php if ($row['image'] == '') {}
else {echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['image'])."'>";} ?>
<?php if ($row['video'] == '') {}
else {echo "<iframe src={$row['video']}></iframe>";} ?></div>`
```

So basically it's either a video or an image which works fine but then I implemented an infinite scroll to my blog which echoes the data from the database through and if statement like so:

```
if ($results) { 

while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
echo '

<div><h3>'.$obj->headline.'</h3> </div>

<div><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode('.$obj->image.')."'></div>'
```

So I wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to transfer that if statement within this echo so that it display an image firstly and then knows whether one is present or when a video is present within the database.

Thanks in advance for any help.

PS: I'm very new to coding/php!

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Just split up the `echo` into multiple statements:

```
while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
    echo '<div>';
    if ($row['image'] == '') {
    } else {
        echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['image'])."'>";
    }
    if ($row['video'] == '') {
    } else {
        echo "<iframe src={$row['video']}></iframe>";
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure if i'm implementing this right but it's not working... I'm trying to put the first if statement within the second if statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
//first initialize a variable as a string 
$result="";
while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
$result.="<div>";
if (!empty($obj['image'])){    
   $result.="<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($obj['image'])."'>";
}
elseif (!empty($obj['video'])){
   $result.="<iframe src={$obj['video']}></iframe>";
}else{
     //show some notification or leave it
     //echo 'not Found';
}
$result.="</div>";
}
//finally you need to print the result variable.
echo $result;
```